# How to send a message on Microsoft teams with new line character while importing the message from an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a table in Microsoft Excel which generates a piece of string in A15 cell (Last blue cell in Col A), this piece of string contains a new line character which was created using char(10).

[image]

Now I have created a Microsoft Flow automation which reads this table and post it on one of my channel on Microsoft Teams.
My problem is that the the new line character is totally getting discarded in the process and the entire string comes as one line in the final message on Microsoft Teams, Is there any way to fix this issue.

I have added my flow below

[image]

This is how I get the Output message using Microsoft flow automation:

[image]

But this is what I really want the output message to look like:

[image]

This is the output of the test run where everything looks fine to me in here. I am unable to pin down the issue

[image]

Any suggestion or help guys will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like your HTMLBody does not recognize Excel's ```Char(10)``` as a line break. Try to substitute these by the HTML version of linebreak ```<br>``` instead when you generate the string and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Man, That did work

Comment: You're welcome, I've posted my comment as an answer as well in case anyone else stumbles upon your question when having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flow is generated by HTML code, but the line break is set as the Excel value of a line break `Char(10)`. HTML will not recognize this as a line break and ignore it. When generating the cell that is to be the output, replace the `Char(10)` with the HTML version `<br>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use \r\n\r\n in the message where you want to break the line.